# Java ArrayStoreException when storing class implementing interface

Tags: java, arrays, interface

Hi I'm getting this Java ArrayStoreException when I try to store class that implements interface into array that's defined as array of interfaces.
Here's the code:

```
private Individual[] individuals;
/*
* other fields and methods here
*/

//This method runs alright
public void initializePopulationBinary() {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfPopulation; i++) {
        BinaryIndividual individual = new BinaryIndividual();
        individual.generateRandomIndividual();
        this.individuals[i] = individual;
    }
}
//This methods throws exception
public void initializePopulationString() {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfPopulation; i++) {
        StringIndividual individual = new StringIndividual();
        individual.generateRandomIndividual();
        this.individuals[i] = individual;
    }
}
```

Individual is interface that both classes BinaryIndividual and StringIndividual implement. Where is the problem?

Comment: Show us the complete stack trace of the exception, the code of the the three classes, and the code that creates the array.

Comment: Likely instance `Individual[]` array was initialized as `new SomeImplementingClass[]`, hence storing instances of the other implementing class would throw the `ArrayStoreException`. Hard to tell with the currently displayed code.

Comment: Yes you are right see my other comments I was indeed initialising it as SomeImplementingClass instead of interface. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `ArrayStoreException` documentation:

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.

My guess is that you initialize the `individuals` somewhere like this:

```
individuals = new BinaryIndividual[someLength];
```

Try to initialize it this way: `individuals = new Individual[someLength];`

Comment: Oh yes my bad so stupid mistake, I was refractoring the code that was initially using only BinaryIndividuals and now I want to use different type individuals as well. Thanks my bad

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your array first with some length:

```
Individual[] individuals = new Individual[sizeOfPopulation];
```

Comment: Yes you are correct I was initialising it into specific BinaryIndividuals instead of just Individuals. Thank you for your help guys I haven't spotted my mistake and I was sure there was something else wrong